# I added online JavaScript in my website. How can I change HTML in my webpage which is added by that JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

When I add the below script to my Web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>
```

This script adds below JavaScript in my web page:

```
    var br=document;
    br.writeln("<b>Quote of the Day</b><br>");
    br.writeln("Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how 
    close they were to success when they gave up.<br>");
```

Now I do not want "Quote of the day" in my webpage. How can I modify it?
If you open this link https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js you can see the code this Js file is adding in my webpage.

Comment: then, uh, don't add the script.

Comment: "When I add the below script to my Web page ...".  Remove it?

Comment: Search for it in the DOM the delete it, its in its own node and right before a `<br>`, easy to find.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle I'm pretty sure the script changes daily.  It's a quote of the day script.  See https://www.brainyquote.com/link/

Comment: It's quote of the day script. It changes daily. @NicoVanBelle

Comment: So to clarify, you just want the `<b>Quote of the Day</b>` part removed then?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Aaah I see :D My bad.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Exactly help me.

Comment: @Cruiser I want to show quotes on daily basis. That's why I am using that script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the script in an element that can be targeted with CSS and set the `<b>` for that element to `display:none;`.  Optinaly, you can also hide the `<br>` it includes as well with `.quote-of-the-day b + br`.

```css
.quote-of-the-day b, .quote-of-the-day b + br {display:none}
```

```html
<div class="quote-of-the-day">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>
</div>
```

This gives you a lot of freedom to style as you see fit.  For instance, the bellow inlines the author and places the quote in a styled blockquote.

```css
.quote-of-the-day b, .quote-of-the-day br {display:none}
.quote-of-the-day {
  padding: 1em;
  border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  margin: 1em;
  color: #333;
}
.quote-of-the-day a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c55;
  font-style: italic;
}
.quote-of-the-day a:before {
  content: '\00a0\2014\00a0';
  color: #333;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<blockquote class="quote-of-the-day">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: It worked! Now can you please tell me how can I remove author? or put the author on the same line as the quote?

Comment: Open this link then you will get what its adding in my web page.
https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js

Comment: @AlamzaibFarooq You can remove the author with `.quote-of-the-day a {display:none}`.  To just inline it, hide all the break tags: `.quote-of-the-day br {display:none}`

Answer (score 1):

select that piece of code and remove it.

```
$("b").each(function() {
    $(this).empty(); // $(this).remove(); 
});
```

be more selective:

```
$("b").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() == "Quote of the Day")
        $(this).empty(); // $(this).remove();
    } 
});
```

Comment: <br> tag is still there how can I remove it too?

Comment: `br.writeln("<b>Quote of the Day</b><br>");` See this code which is added my brainyqoute.

Comment: use $(this).remove();

Answer (score 1):

Add this code after including script from BrainyQuote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace("<b>Quote of the Day</b><br>", "");
</script>
```

Comment: Oh man, you are the genius. Now tell me one more thing. How can I show author in same line. I mean author name right after qoute. Below is total code that javascript putting in my webpage:
var br=document;
br.writeln("<b>Quote of the Day</b><br>");
br.writeln("Many of life's failures are people who did not realize how close they were to success when they gave up.<br>");
br.writeln("<a href=\"http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/t/thomas_a_edison.html.html?utm_source=script&utm_medium=feeds&utm_campaign=quotebr\" target=\"_blank\">Thomas A. Edison</a>");
br.writeln("<br>");

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementsByTagName('b')[0].remove();
</script>
```